# android how to click the button which is in the listview item to delete that item

Tags: android, listview

Custom List adapter class.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image =  (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        holder.qty = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_qty);
        holder.delete_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //holder.image
    holder.name.setText(productArray.get(position).getName());
    holder.price.setText("$"+ productArray.get(position).getPrice());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, quantity);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.qty.setAdapter(adapter);
    return convertView;
}
```

How to click the delete_btn to delete the listview item. I don't know how to access the listview. pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside getView() :

```
       holder.delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    yourlist.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i know, the problem is how to access the listview then call the remove method of it

Comment: Use interface to comunicate. You can pass it to button using setTag method

Comment: any reference? or I do it later thanks@PiotrGolinski

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need selected item position also to change you data set(list items)

so your `getView();` will be

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        .......
        holder.delete_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        holder.delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //selected item position
                int itemPosition=(int)view.getTag();
                //deletion stuff
                productArray.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.delete_btn.setTag(position)//set item position 

    holder.name.setText(productArray.get(position).getName());
    .......
    return convertView;
}
```

**Updated :** 
check button onClick listener method. Refer @Nikhil @nag

Comment: does defining a final int storing position work?  once i get the position, how to delete from listview

Comment: As posted by @Nag using `yourList.remove(itemPosition);` inside onclick listener and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: how to get the listview in adapter class

Comment: how to get the listview in adapter class : means. Check above code working or not.